# UIView animating its own height

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have made a simple example of a UIView inside a UIViewController, so that when I tap on the inner view, it increases and decreases its height. That works fine, but I can't make the height transition animate.

Here is the view controller, followed by the view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let theView = MyView()
        theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(theView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 50.0),
            theView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant:0.0),
            theView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 925)
            ])
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {
    fileprivate var closedChanger = NSLayoutConstraint()
    fileprivate var isOpen = false
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        setupView()
    }
    
    fileprivate func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        closedChanger = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            closedChanger // start off with it shorter
        ])
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:))))
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.closedChanger.constant = self.isOpen ? self.closedChanger.constant - 25 : self.closedChanger.constant + 25
            // self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        isOpen.toggle()
    }
}
```

The `layoutIfNeeded` doesn't affect it. Is a UIView not allowed to animate its own height change?

Comment: I do it all the time, but maybe not how you are? (1) I use auto layout, and each **constant** constraint is set to `isActive = true`. (2) I set up arrays of the constraints I need changed, and activate the one I wish to start with. (3) I trigger the constraint changes in various ways, but to actually execute it I first (a) deactivate the current constraint array then (b) activate the array I wan and finally (c) use `UIView.animate. From what I see, you are trying too much to combine things I think. My changes affect a "slide out" both horizontal and vertical. Maybe break it down and test?

Comment: Set the constraint constant *outside* the animation closure and call `setNeedsLayout` inside the animation closure.

Comment: @Paulw11 - same result. The change in the height works, but there is no animation.

Comment: @dfd - `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` automatically sets isActive to true. I've tried similar to what you suggest, but I always get the same result: the change in the height happens, but no animation for it.

Comment: You seem to have two height constraints; one of 925 that you set when you add the view and then the "open/close" height constraint. are you getting conflicting constraints warnings?  Normally when animation fails it is because something else triggers another layout pass during the animation which causes the layout to be set immediately.

Comment: Agreed, @Paulw11, so I removed the height constraint in the view controller, which solved the conflicting constraint warning. But still, although the view's height changes on click, I can't get it to animate. (I am suspecting it is because although a view can animate a subview, a view cannot animate itself. Looking for verification of that!)

Comment: My deleted answer (obviously) didn't help. But which UIView are you trying to animate? `MyView`? It's a subview of `ViewController.view`. Why not call `UIView.animate` from there? (please, not trying to sound critical, trying to help.)

Comment: @dfd - agreed, calling the animation from the view controller makes sense; I'm pleased though, that with `superview`, I can keep the animation within the affected view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are kind of right when you say that a view can't animate itself.  The problem is that you need to animate the change to the containing view, since that the is the view hierarchy that is changing.

You need to make the change to the constraint outside of the animation block, and then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview in the animation block.

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.closedChanger.constant = self.isOpen ? self.closedChanger.constant - 25 : self.closedChanger.constant + 25
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {     
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    isOpen.toggle()
}
```